# Alternative to "echo" withe less code/characters?

Tags: php

As per the title, is there a quicker way to display something in PHP without using echo, so for example is you are using GET[1] taking code from a parsed parameter "1" and displaying it to the screen.

Comment: Here's a question for you: ***why do you mind?***

Comment: You understood meaning of word *"optimization"* wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are shorthand `echo` statements that looks like:

```
<?=$_GET[1]?>
```

although you must have this feature turned on.

[short-open-tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)

Comment: In the newest versions of PHP is it not on by default?

Comment: Since PHP 5.4.0, `<?=` is always available.

Comment: Cool, that's what I thought.